# check if request file is type zip

Tags: node.js, file, file-type

Im using the following code to get single files/ zip from postman.

In the request im asking for a file original name and can check if the file `originalname` contain `.zip` or not ,is there a better way to check if it single file or zip ?

```
update function (req, res) {
        if (req.file) {
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've had to do this in the past and the cleanest way I've found is to check the `mimetype` of the file from the request:

`if(req.file.mimetype === 'application/zip')`

Bonus being there's no need for external depedencies.

Comment: Well yes it's a bonus, but sometimes we would use ready-to-use modules to make it easier for us to write code, shorten it and make it more consistent :)

Comment: Absolutely sometimes we should. I'm just still scarred from how prevalent `left-pad` was. For one-liners like this, where there's a built-in solution you have to agree that it's potentially overkill to use a library.

Comment: Well yes, may be in this case.

Comment: FYI, it can also be `application/x-zip-compressed`

Answer (score 4):

You can simply do it using the **[`file-type` module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-type)**, it's made for this.

### [file-type](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-type)

> Detect the file type of a Buffer/Uint8Array

**fileType(input)**

> Returns an `Object` with:

- `ext` - One of the supported file types
- `mime` - The MIME type
- Or `null`  when no match.

### Usage:

This is how to check for the file type:

```
const readChunk = require('read-chunk');
const fileType = require('file-type');
const buffer = readChunk.sync('myFile.zip', 0, 4100);

if (fileType(buffer).ext == "zip")) {
  console.log("Zip file loaded");
}
```